# Finding minimum cycle in an undirected graph using boost graph library

Tags: algorithm, c++11, graph, graph-theory, boost-graph

I have an undirected adjacency boost graph without weights. I need to find minimum cycles in the graph.

[image]

minimum cycle: `c1[1 2 3 4 ]` , `c2[2 3 6 5]`, ... 
but for example: `[1 2 5 6 3 4]` is NOT a `minimum cycle` because it contains cycle `c1` in it.

I went through different posts during my search, but eventually I end up with solutions to get the all cycles in a graph but not minimum cycles. From [Finding all cycles in undirected graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367801/finding-all-cycles-in-undirected-graphs) and [Cycles in an Undirected Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526331/cycles-in-an-undirected-graph/47320121#47320121) I understood the best way is doing a `DFS` search and look for `back_edges`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922325/find-a-cycle-in-an-undirected-graph-boost-and-return-its-vertices-and-edges) thread gives some solutions with boost, but it gives all the cycles not the minimum cycle and it doesn't have implementation. [Algorithm for finding minimal cycles in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782898/algorithm-for-finding-minimal-cycles-in-a-graph) discusses also how to get the minimum cycle but there is no solution for it.

I appreciate if someone has a workaround for this (better in boost graph library)?

**Update:** Minimum cycle here means in the set of vertices of a candidate cycle, there shouldn't be another direct connection between two vertices. For example in `c3[1 2 5 6 7 4]` there is no backedge between vertices, so it is a `minimum`. But in `c4[1 2 3 6 7 4]` there is an edge between `[3 4]` that can make a cycle `[1 2 3 4]`, so we don't consider `c4` as a minimum.

Comment: So `[1 2 5 6 3 4]` is not minimal, because `c1` is in it. How about `[1 2 5 6 7 4]`? It is not minimal for me, but it doesn't contain `c1` or one of the other smaller cycles. Do you want that to be a valid "minimal cycle" or not?

Comment: You need to associate costs with each edge, simply drawing lines greater and smaller does not make a cycle bigger or smaller

Comment: @LuaiGhunim that's not what defines a minimal cycle here (it's not shortest paths, and shortest paths for constant weights is BFS, still has a useful definition)

Comment: @sehe in that case i can reform that graph and by placing 6 inside 1 4 2 3 without removing any edge and graph is totally isomorph with the first one ==> Both are equal.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim yes. I can do that too. On first intuition I'd say that makes no difference to the question.

Comment: @sehe Yes that does. Then you have two cycles inside  `1 4 3 2` and `1 4 3 2` becomes the biggest cycle because he defines the cycle as smallest which is contained in another.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim That depends on how "minimum cycle" is defined. Which is what we're trying to ask from OP.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim I see that you have a valid point here. By rearranging the vertices, in the image we may have another cycle inside the other, but I specifically mentioned that I don't have `weight` on the edges or they have `equal weight`. So `minimum` in this concept is not minimum cost but set of vertices that doesn't contain other set of vertices which could be a cycle.

Comment: @sehe To answer your first question, `[1 2 5 6 7 4]` doesn't have any set of vertices that possibly could make a cycle, so it is a minimum cycle in that sense.