# Detecting cyclic pairs

Tags: c++, detection, std-pair, cyclic, stdset

Assume a `std::set< std::pair<char, char> >`, can somebody suggest an algorithm or approach to check whether there are cyclic pairs?

e.g.

```
std::set< std::pair<char, char> > cyclic = { {'A', 'B'}, {'B', 'C'}, {'C', 'A'} };
std::set< std::pair<char, char> > not_cyclic = { {'A', 'B'}, {'B', 'C'}, {'C', 'C'} };

isCyclic(cyclic);     // true
isCyclic(not_cyclic); // false
```

I don't want to use any extern library (c++ library is allowed), since the function `bool isCyclic(const std::set< std::pair<char, char> >& set);` will only be used once and it should be overkill to `#include` a big library like boost just for that one function...

Any ideas how to tackle this problem?

Comment: What you have is an adjacency list. Use it to build a tree using DFS, and look for a back edge. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: What about `{{A,B},{B,A}}`? Or `{{A,B},{B,C},{A,C}}`?

Comment: @Beta The first one is still the cyclic one that I'm looking for and the second is not.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a graph, characters being its vertices and pairs in the set - the edges. You can detect whether there is a cycle easily using any search for instance `BFS` or `DFS`. 
Also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8144977/812912). Don't mind that it deals with undirected case as the algorithm is the same.