# Shortest Paths in undirected cyclic graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

Can someone please explain how given an undirected graph G = (V; E); edge lengths le > 0; and edge edges in E.

We can generate the length of the shortest cycle containing edge e.

I understand how to do this in directed graphs, but im not sure how to approach the problem with an undirected graph.

Comment: Remove e={v1,v2) and find the shortest path from v1 to v2?

Comment: Why do you have a `DAG` tag on this question, if the graph is undirected and you are looking for a cycle? If the ends of `e` are `v1` and `v2`, then the shortest cycle in undirected graph would be the trivial one `v1-v2-v1` :-) I'm sure this isn't what you're looking for, so you may want to clarify that the cycle needs to have at least three edges.

Comment: @n.m. Brilliant! Why did you not add this as an answer?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Agreed, now my solution seems awkwardly complicated -.-

Comment: @phant0m Why, I think your solution is pretty clean, too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cycles in an Undirected Graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526331/cycles-in-an-undirected-graph)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Well, just considering the explanations, mine needs a lot more words... without giving more understanding

Comment: @Mr.Alien It's not a duplicate. This asks for the shortest cycle containing a specific edge. The other is about cycle detection.

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying the graph: Let *e* be an edge *(u, v)*. Choose one of the two nodes—I'll choose *u*—and run an ordinary Dijkstra/BFS starting from *u* with one minor modification: When making the first hop, you *must not* add *v* to the queue. Now search for *v*.