# Cycle detection in a 2-tuple python list

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Given a list of edges in 2-tuple, (source, destination), is there any efficient way to determine if a cycle exists? Eg, in the example below, a cycle exists because 1 -> 3 -> 6 -> 4 -> 1.  One idea is to calculate the number of occurrence of each integer in the list (again, is there any efficient way to do this?). Is there any better way? I am seeing a problem with 10,000 of 2-tuple edge information.

```
a = [(1,3), (4,6), (3,6), (1,4)]
```

Comment: What do you mean by a __cycle__? How do you recognize it?

Comment: The layout of the numbers 1 3 6 and 4 on a numpad represent a 'cycle' I guess

Comment: There is no cycle in your example. You can reach `6` over two edges but there is no cycle back to `1`.

Comment: @LutzHorn: there is if the graph is undirected

Comment: True, but `->` indicates direction. I would represent an undirected graph as `1-2`, not `1->2`.

Comment: related: [Cycles in an Undirected Graph](http://stackoverflow.com/q/526331/4279)

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection

Comment: thanks mskimm, that's what I'm looking for. Some good python implementation for cycle detection.

Comment: Do you only need to know if a cycle exists, or do you also need to know what they are? If the first, note that if all the nodes are connected, number of edges = number of nodes - 1 iff there are no cycles.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Actually it's more like edges = number of nodes - number of connected components

Comment: @mskimm Actually that is not what OP needs, since nodes have degree > 1

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to find a cycle in the undirected graph represented by your edge list and you don't want to count "trivial" cycles of size 1 or 2.

You can still use a standard [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), but you need to be a bit careful about the node coloring (a simple flag to signal which nodes you have already visited is not sufficient):

```
from collections import defaultdict

edges = [(1,3), (4,6), (3,6), (1,4)]
adj = defaultdict(set)
for x, y in edges:
    adj[x].add(y)
    adj[y].add(x)

col = defaultdict(int)
def dfs(x, parent=None):
    if col[x] == 1: return True
    if col[x] == 2: return False
    col[x] = 1
    res = False
    for y in adj[x]:
        if y == parent: continue
        if dfs(y, x): res = True
    col[x] = 2
    return res

for x in adj:
    if dfs(x):
        print "There's a cycle reachable from %d!" % x
```

This will detect if there is a **back edge** in the depth-first forest that spans at least 2 levels. This is exactly the case if there is a simple cycle of size >= 2. By storing parent pointers you can actually print the cycle as well if you found it.

For large graphs you might want to use an explicit stack instead of recursion, as [illustrated on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode).