# Determine when a polygon is closed by a new side

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My program has a `List<Vector3>` of unique points (A, B, C, ...) which are created each time a user draws a unique line (1, 2, 3, ...). Lines are stored in a `List<int>` where every two ints are the indices of each point to form a single line. No two lines can have the same two points, no points can occupy the same position, and stray lines are allowed.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Tzm.png)[image: Diagram]

```
Points: {A, B, C, D, E} //Each letter represents a 2d or 3d position
Sides: {0,1,1,2,1,3,3,4,4,2} //(Each int is an index in Points, every pair is a side)
```

I am trying to find an efficient way of determining when a new line (Green, 5) closes a polygon with any number of sides. I have a way of doing this: iterating through each line connected to each side of the new line(and all subsequent lines) until they share a point (D).

[Completed Polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M575W.png)[image: Completed Polygon]

My only problem here is that the more sides a polygon has, I need to do exponentially more checks (Every two additional sides on the polygon causes me to check one layer deeper on all attached sides).

Is there a way to reduce the number of checks I need to do in order to close the polygon?

Not exactly the same as [Cycles in an Undirected Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526331/cycles-in-an-undirected-graph). This knows that at least one cycle is present and connected to a given side, and is looking for only the smallest cycle possible connected to that side. Other sides are irrelevant and it should avoid them.

Comment: What should happen when an edge is drawn between A and C? Should it create a triangle adjacent to the quadrilateral or a larger polygon where edge 2 is ignored? Can polygons overlap?

Comment: A second polygon should be created (A, B, C) with the same rules as the first (C, B, D, E)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cycles in an Undirected Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526331/cycles-in-an-undirected-graph), as it should be noted that your list is an undirected graph and polygons are cycles or loops within that graph.

Comment: Not exactly. This knows that at least one cycle is present and connected to a given side, and is looking for only the smallest cycle possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the level of optimization you need. For simple pictures (some what like < 10 - 100k lines) you can get away with running a BFS every time.

High level algorithm:

First you need something to store the graph using one of the [Graph representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)). Then whenever the user draws a line you take either of the two points and do a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) on that point.

If you can reach the same point with your BFS and the path length is > 2 then you have a polygon.

The catch would be that since the graph is bidirectional you need to be careful when walking thru it. Do not re-visit nodes that you have already visited.

Comment: This is essentially what I was doing in the second diagram, although I didn't know what it was called.

Basically I do a BFS from each side, with side E and C as the top layer of each. 

I go down one layer in each and check for matches, that would form a triangle. If nothing matches, I drop another layer in either side(C) and check for matches again, this would be a quad. If nothing matches there, I drop a layer in the opposite side(E) and check again. I was hoping something would be more efficient, but this is probably the fastest solution for now.

Comment: @Philip I think you understood it wrong. you only need to do BFS from ONE side. The goal is to find a circular path back to itself without repeating edge. BFS is O(n) where n is the number of edges(lines) so its a linear algorithm instead of exponential.